# https to http for some URLs with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http, ssl, https

I tried some code-hints I found on some Questions-answers but I did not had any luck.

So I as my Question.

I want to redirect some URL's form https to http.

A part of my htaccess code is follwing. But It doesn't work the URL still stays on SSL.
The main SSL direct comes from the Server.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php?lang=de&Itemid=231
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php?lang=en&Itemid=337
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php?lang=fr&Itemid=338
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=58&Itemid=231&lang=de
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=58&Itemid=337&lang=en
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=58&Itemid=338&lang=fr
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

---

I tried to solve my issue with Sumurai8's code-snippet. But I did not had any luck. It still stays on SSL. Could that be because the SSL is from the Apache-Server Confixx config?

I also checked the Cache. Also I was not able to use your code with the simplified code. It said, that it could not finish the request -> Loop.

> The query string is not included in the first argument of RewriteRule, or can be matched with %{REQUEST_URI}

Do I need to add a new rule to match the conditions?

Like:

```
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L]
```

Update:

The htaccess file is located in the html folder. So not in a subfolder.

The hole code at the moment is following:

```
Action php /cgi-php53/php
AddHandler php53 .php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/index.php?lang=de&Itemid=231 [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/index.php?lang=en&Itemid=337 [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/index.php?lang=fr&Itemid=338 [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=58&Itemid=231&lang=de [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=58&Itemid=337&lang=en [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=58&Itemid=338&lang=fr
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L]
```

inactive conditions and rules

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^chimia.ch
#RewriteRule (.*) http://scg.ch/$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myow.ch
#RewriteRule (.*) http://scg.ch/$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^polycoll.ch
#RewriteRule (.*) http://scg.ch/$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^swiss-chem-soc.ch
#RewriteRule (.*) http://scg.ch/$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^youngchemists.ch
#RewriteRule (.*) http://scg.ch/$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.chimia.ch
#RewriteRule (.*) http://scg.ch/$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myow.ch
#RewriteRule (.*) http://scg.ch/$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.polycoll.ch
#RewriteRule (.*) http://scg.ch/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and then some redirects like:

```
Redirect /cours/2014-aa1f https://scg.ch/index.php?option=com_superevents&redirect=category&catid=74&Itemid=525&task=group&view=details&id=2674&lang=en

Redirect /cours/2014-aa2f https://scg.ch/index.php?option=com_superevents&redirect=category&catid=74&Itemid=525&task=group&view=details&id=2678&lang=en

Redirect /cours/2014-aa3f https://scg.ch/index.php?option=com_superevents&redirect=category&catid=74&Itemid=525&task=group&view=details&id=2689&lang=en
```

a lot more redirects

```
Redirect /roempp https://scg.ch/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=926:roempp-online-special-offer-for-scs-members&catid=9:scg-news&Itemid=112&lang=en

Redirect /login https://scg.ch/index.php?option=com_comprofiler&task=login&lang=en


ErrorDocument 404 /
```

Thanks for more help in advance. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Your rules seem fine, except for one thing. The query string is not included in the first argument of `RewriteRule`, or can be matched with `%{REQUEST_URI}`. Furthermore, the `?` character in regex means "match the previous character 0 or 1 times" and the `.` character means "match any character". You need to match it with either `%{QUERY_STRING}` or match it with `%{THE_REQUEST}`.

You can simplify it by moving the common part (`index.php`) to the first argument of your RewriteRule, having the required HTTPS on before all conditions that describe each possible query string. By chaining those conditions with OR flags, only one of those have to be true, as long as one of them is true.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=de&Itemid=231$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=en&Itemid=337$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=fr&Itemid=338$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=58&Itemid=231&lang=de$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=58&Itemid=337&lang=en$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=58&Itemid=338&lang=fr$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi Sumurai8,

Thanks for the respond and help so far. But I'm still stock with the issue. Perhaps you could find the bug in my answer above.

Comment: Hi, StackOverflow is not a forum. You therefore should not post a 'reply' to my answer as an answer to your question, unless it actually solves the problem outlined in your question. You can better edit your question with new information and notify me with a comment like you did here.

Comment: @konzeptplus Where is your .htaccess located, and does it contain more rules? What rules does it contain then?

Comment: Hi @Sumurai8. Thanks for the help so far. And sorry about the secound Answer. I was not aware of this. Now I get it. I updated some infos in my secound "answer". Thanks in advance. 
The htaccess is on root and the hole code is in the secound answer update. Thanks

Comment: Hi Sumurai8, All the Questions and updates about it are now in the 1 Question. 
Could it be that it is not working because the url which has to be chaned to a http is in the registerd area? And/Or because the SSL gets also pushed by the cms config?

Comment: I assume you have rules related to your cms already in your .htaccess? What happens if you comment those out?

Comment: I don't have special rules for the cms in the htaccess. I only have the conditions / rules as shown above. So there is the rücke about www to plane http and the new ones. And beneath it some redirects for subfolders and short urls.

Comment: Strange. None of your rules redirect random urls to index.php in your question, but if I go to `scg.ch/dbgawoighasdghi` it first redirects me to https, then redirects me to `/index.php?lang=de`. I don't have a server with https enabled, but the rule should in theory work. If you are sure there are no rules anywhere for the cms system, I am unsure what could cause that behaviour.